# Testcafe expect passes if await used but not if methods chained

Tags: javascript, testcafe

Take this Testcafe code:

```js
test
    .page('https://testsite.com')
    ('button hidden after clicked', async t => {
        await t
            .expect(await Selector('button.cc-banner__button-accept').visible).ok({ timeout: 5000 })
            .setNativeDialogHandler(() => true)
            .click(await Selector('button.cc-banner__button-accept'))
            .expect(await Selector('button.cc-banner__button-accept').visible).notOk({ timeout:1000 });
```

The above fails when Testcafe runs.

However, the code below passes:

```js
test
    .page('https://testsite.com')
    ('button hidden after clicked', async t => {
        await t
            .expect(await Selector('button.cc-banner__button-accept').visible).ok({ timeout: 5000 })
            .setNativeDialogHandler(() => true)
            .click(await Selector('button.cc-banner__button-accept'));
        await t
            .expect(await Selector('button.cc-banner__button-accept').visible).notOk({ timeout:1000 });
```

Why is this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JS evaluates the real element value for `Selector` at the time of chain compiling. (JS works in this way). It means that the first test you evaluate calculates `await Selector('button.cc-banner__button-accept').visible` for the whole chain only once and then this value is used for checking. Since you get the value only once, the test fails as expected. You should remove `await` inside, before `Selector` inside assertions, as you can see in CLI warnings.

[image]